# Accessing a shared file?

Tags: c#, .net, shared-directory, windows-share

I'm trying to read a file body from a Windows shared folder by it's UNC path, and getting this exception: `The process cannot access the file '\\<someIP>\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex141017.log' because it is being used by another process.`
However, this file isn't really locked by any process. I can view it from my PC using a text editor, etc.

I'm using this code to read the file:

```
var logFile = File.ReadAllText(logPath);
```

and

```
var logFile = (string)null;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(logPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        logFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

(both fail)

Any ideas why this exception might happen, when the file isn't really locked by any process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing FileShare.Delete to FileShare.ReadWrite. This will allow the file to be read and written by other applications simultaneously. In other words

```
var logFile = (string)null;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(logPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        logFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this can't work, as FileShare.ReadWrite is more access restrictive than FileShare.Delete. But it does. Why?

Comment: Delete and ReadWrite in fact mean two quite different things. From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx

**Delete:** Allows subsequent deleting of a file.

**ReadWrite:** Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I am still facing with the problem. I am using .net core 3.1 on Mac with the same code "FileShare.ReadWrite", and same error System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '../log_1.txt' because it is being used ber process.  I can open the file with vs code