# How can I open a Program with a logfil multiple times? (C#)

Tags: c#, logging, streamwriter, logfile

I have this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\temp\log.txt"))
        {
            Log("Test1", w);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
    {
        w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        w.WriteLine(logMessage);
        w.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

when I start this code twice at the same time, I get an exception because the file is already opened in the other instance.

Is there any alternative to "StreamWriter" which can write the same file from two instances?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi processes read&write one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690537/multi-processes-readwrite-one-file)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421683/accessing-a-shared-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a shared file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421683/accessing-a-shared-file)

Comment: Use a library such as [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually StramWriter needs to close the file handler after writing something to it. So by putting **Using** statement, you gave this task (Closing the file handler) to the `Using` (it's One of it benefits) so if you wait in `Using` block for any reason (you have added a Console.ReadLine()) the file Handler will open until the end of that block.

if correct above codes:

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\temp\log.txt"))
         {
             Log("Test1", w);
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

     public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
     {
         w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
         w.WriteLine(logMessage);
         w.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
     }
 }
```

there should be a small chance of concurrency. but it may occur and you can use try catch block and **while** statement to insure that your log, has been submitted.

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         bool WriteDone = false;
         while(!WriteDone)
         {
             try 
             {
                 using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\temp\log.txt"))
                 {
                    Log("Test1", w);
                 }
                 WriteDone = true;
              } 
              catch 
              { 
                   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for 1s and try again
              }
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

     public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
     {
         w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
         w.WriteLine(logMessage);
         w.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
     }
 }
```